# Adding cell.textLabel.text value to an array and displaying it

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

i have a UItableView and i have two buttons on each cell. You can add or subtract `1` from the `cell`'s `textLabel`. I add the cells current value +1 with this:

```
  - (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender{
     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[cell.textLabel.text intValue] +1];//<--- num is an NSNumber
     number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:num, nil];//<---- number is an NSMutableArray
     [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

and I am trying to subtract the text and store it in an array with this:

```
    - (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender
{
        if ( [[cell.textLabel text] intValue] == 0){     


     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[num intValue] +0];
     [number addObject:num];
         [myTableView reloadData];

     }
     else{
     num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[num intValue] -1];
     [number addObject:num];
     [myTableView reloadData];
     }
}
```

and im trying to set the `cell.textLabel.text` in the cellForRow like this:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
     {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];


     } 
    cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//<---IM USING THIS LINE TO SET THE NEW TEXTLABEL
    cell.textLabel.text = @"1";


return cell;
}
```

**MY PROBLEM**

So, the addition works, but the subtraction does not. It doesnt work at all when i press the button on the cell. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of pointing out the obvious... you seem to have hard-coded the text property to @"1".

```
cell.textLabel.text = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//<---IM USING THIS LINE TO SET THE NEW TEXTLABEL
cell.textLabel.text = @"1";
```

The first line is probably doing what you think... but then you're immediately changing it back to @"1".

**EDIT** - Based on clarification in comments, here's what I think you want to do.  I will modify your own code as posted.

Note that I put my addition into `viewDidLoad` as an example.  You could do this in init, or any number of other places, at whatever point you know how many cells you want to show.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.number = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    for (int i = 0; i < [HOW MANY CELLS DO YOU WANT?]; i++) {
        [self.number addObject:@"1"];
    }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)addLabelText:(id)sender {
// Note that I'm assuming here that your button is a direct child of the cell.
// If not, you'll need to change this.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [sender superview];
    NSInteger newNumber = [cell.textLabel.text intValue] + 1;
    NSString *newNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newNumber];

    [self.number replaceObjectAtIndex:cell.tag withObject:newNumberString];

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)subtractLabelText:(id)sender {
// Note that I'm assuming here that your button is a direct child of the cell.
// If not, you'll need to change this.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [sender superview];
    NSInteger newNumber = [cell.textLabel.text intValue] - 1;
    newNumber = (newNumber < 0) ? 0 : newNumber;

    NSString *newNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newNumber];

    [self.number replaceObjectAtIndex:cell.tag withObject:newNumberString];

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.tag = indexPath.row; // Important for identifying the cell easily later
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I don't want to get too much more in depth, but I would recommend you take a look at [reloading only the cell modified](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a), instead of calling [myTableView reloadData] every time.

Comment: okay, so should i remove this line? i need it to display `1` as soon as the cell is created and i cant seem to do that either. Is there another place i could put that line? Thank you for the reply!!

Comment: @iProRage - It's a little hard to tell what your intent is based on just the code you've posted.  From what I see, this will not update the cell you touched's value, but the value of the cell at the index the value gets added to `number` at.  If you intend to change the value of the cell that was touched, you need to create your number array beforehand, with @"1" as the initial value for each cell's index, then change the value at the correct index for the cell that was touched.

Comment: i am just trying to add and subtract `1` to the cell. I did this before without adding the value to an array and when i scrolled a cell out of the view and when it returned, the value was all messed up. And now im adding it to an array, because i read that it will fix my problem. And where should i set the initial value of `1` in the array at? The cellForRow method, or the viewDidLoad? Thanks again doug!!

Comment: No problem dude.  Okay, I think I understand what you're trying to do.  I'll update my answer to address that.  You may also want to take a look at using properties.  It looks like you're accessing all of your class variables directly, and managing them directly.  From what I see, it's probably creating some memory leaks.

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot! and how come it would be creating memory leaks just from accessing them directly?

Comment: In your addLabelText method you're calling this every time `number = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:num, nil]`.  That will cause leaks because you aren't releasing the previously allocated NSMutableArray.  I'd highly recommend you read through Apple's tutorials memeory management if you haven't--well worth the read.  Cheers!

Comment: awesome!! Thanks a bunch for your time and effort doug! you are a good guy! :D

Comment: Not a problem dude, I enjoy helping.  If you feel like this answers your question, please don't forget to accept it.  Good luck!